# How to plot a grouped bar chart from a dataframe with several columns in x

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

This is my first time trying to plot some data in Python.
I have a dataframe like this one:

| city | zone | category | searches_ok | searches_null |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Buenos Aires | Zone1 | Books | 12 | 6 |
| Buenos Aires | Zone1 | Home | 7 | 0 |
| Buenos Aires | Zone2 | Books | 5 | 7 |
| Rosario | Zone7 | Home | 25 | 1 |
| Rio de Janeiro | Zone8 | Tech | 55 | 3 |
| Rio de Janeiro | Zone9 | Books | 12 | 7 |
| Sao Paulo | Zone15 | Tech | 34 | 8 |

How would go about plotting this in a grouped bar chart?
I would like for there to be 2 bars (searches_ok and searches_null) for each "combination" of city/zone/category.

Using this:

```
df_arg.set_index("zone")
df.plot(x="zone", y=["searches_ok","searches_null"]
```

I was able to plot a graph with both columns, but only for the "Zone" column...
How would you go about doing that for each combination of city/zone/category ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making your x columns the index:

```
df.set_index(['city','zone','category']).plot.bar(rot=45)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes, like this... Question: do you also change anything in df.plot(x="zone", y=["searches_ok","searches_null"] ? I'm getting a weird graph... I tried also passing the columns in the x axis like this: x=['city','zone','category'], but I get an error saying:   "x must be a label or position"

Comment: Remove your code, just use mine, no `x` param.

Comment: Right! I'm dumb, haha. Thanks man, just what I needed!